# Conflict materialize-css and @angular/material theme

Tags: angular, materialize, angular-material2

In the project added two frameworks [`materialize-css`](https://materializecss.com/getting-started.html) and [`angular-material`](https://material.angular.io/guide/customizing-component-styles) but in angular material components get the style from `materialize` and overriding styles of angular material.

In root `style.css`:

```
@import "~materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

Problem in :

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input placeholder="IP" matInput [(ngModel)]="vds.ip">
</mat-form-field>
```

This view:

[image]

How to resolve this conflict and set angular material styles always main?

Version:

```
Angular 6
angular/material 6.3.3
materialize-css 1.0.0-rc.2
```

Full style css:

```
@import "~materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";

.a-sidenav {
    transform: translateX(0) !important;
    width: 250px !important
}

.a-sidenav h4 {
    padding: 0 30px;
    opacity: .8;
    font-size: 2rem
}

.a-sidenav .bold.last {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 62px;
    width: 100%
}

main, footer {
    margin-left: 250px
}

.content {
    padding: 0 30px
}

.m0 {
    margin: 0
}

.mr1 {
    margin-right: 10px
}

.mb2 {
    margin-bottom: 20px
}

.mb1 {
    margin-bottom: 10px
}

.p10 {
    padding: 10px !important
}

.pointer {
    cursor: pointer
}

.order-row {
    flex-wrap: wrap
}

.order-row .card {
    width: 50%;
    height: 70%;
    min-width: 175px;
    margin-right: 20px
}

.order-img {
    height: 100px !important
}

.frow {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto
}

.page-title {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 25px 0
}

.page-title a {
    color: black;
    opacity: .8
}

#create-modal {
    max-width: 500px
}

.page-subtitle {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 15px 0
}

.page-title h3, .page-title h4 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2.3rem
}

.page-subtitle h4 {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 2rem
}

.order-summary {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding-right: 30px
}

.order-summary p {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important
}

.order-position-input {
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0
}

.order-position-input input {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important
}

.fr {
    display: flex;
    margin-bottom: 15px
}

.fr .col.order {
    width: 120px
}

.fr .col.filter-pickers {
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 40%;
    display: flex
}

.fr .col.filter-pickers .input-field {
    width: 45% !important;
    min-width: 120px;
    margin-right: 20px !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important
}

.fr .col.range {
    width: 40%;
    padding-top: 44px
}

.filter {
    margin-bottom: 15px
}

.hide {
    display: none !important
}

.tap-target {
    background-color: #e0e0e0 !important
}

.btn-floating.tap-target-origin {
    background-color: #bdbdbd !important
}

.auth-block {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 50px
}

.auth-block .card {
    width: 400px
}

.nav-wrapper {
    padding-left: 20px
}

.collection-item-icon {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 10
}

.collection-item-icon i.material-icons:hover {
    color: #f44336 !important;
    transition: .3s color
}

.pl0 {
    padding-left: 0 !important
}

.average-price {
    padding: 15px 0;
    font-size: 20px
}

.analytics-block {
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px
}

.pb3 {
    padding-bottom: 30px
}

hr.style-four {
    height: 12px;
    border: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 12px 12px -12px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: can you try to revert the import statement

Comment: or try the full path                              
 1] "../node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css"

Comment: Could you please explain why you have both - does materialize give something that angular-material does not?

Comment: I made this angular project on stackblitz which is using 
Angular 6 
angular/material 6.4.0 
materialize-css 1.0.0-rc.2 
but there are no issues... you can check here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1d323s

Comment: I made this angular project on stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/materialize-input Which is using 1. Angular 6 2. angular/material 6.4.0 3. materialize-css 1.0.0-rc.2 I used components from angular material and materialize both but there are no issues... Can you please refer to this project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/materialize-input

Comment: I updated my question. Unfortunately, my project is huge and I haven't permission for publishing this code, but I open where I think can be the problem.

Comment: @eric99 not I can't explain my college which white this code leaves away from the company. I want to know it too.

Comment: In inputs you need to remove the matInput attribute to use the materialize css by default...

I also did it in the stackblitz that I sent earlier and just don't use the attributes of angular.material if you don't want to use it's features.

Comment: and also don't use the tags that material.angular provides, instead use the tags and components that are provided by materialize css framework.

You can check https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1d323s as a reference.

Comment: Yes I see, a difficult situation. I would just remove materialize-css and see if anything breaks.

Comment: yes in you're example we saves from double underscore, but  the result we have style from materialize.css single. May be get the style from angular.material like a single instead materialize.css posiible too?

Comment: Yes it's very much possible but for doing that we explicitly have to remove the materialize css from the part we want to (like in our whatever.component.css file). This behaviour occurs because it's a library that styles all the elements.

Comment: Check the stackblitz again, I have edited it and added comments for everything and have also added an example for the input and how you could use it and if my answer has helped you then don't forget to mark it as answer so that other people could benefit from it.

Comment: The stackblitz is not accessible anymore. Does anyone have an solution to reset generic styling for Materialize css.

Comment: And this is why we don't permit answers which don't work if the links go down.

Answer (score 3):

Few days back I renamed all my stackblitz repos and forgot to change it from here. Here's my old answer with the updated link:

I made this angular project on stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/materialize-input

Which is using

Angular 6
angular/material 6.4.0
materialize-css 1.0.0-rc.2
I used components from angular material and materialize both but there are no issues... Can you please refer to this project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/materialize-input

Here's a github repo for this project:
https://github.com/immad-hamid/materialize-input

Comment: can you provide a github repo?

Comment: I sure would add a github repo to my answer by tomorrow.

Comment: @GabrielBitencourt sorry for getting back late to you, really busy these days. Have added the git repo in the updated answer. Here the repo link for your ref: https://github.com/immad-hamid/materialize-input